# Disable submit button after one click in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-disabled

I would like to disable button after one click.

Code:

```
<button id="submitRequest" class="btn btn-primary btn-active"
        ng-disabled="!frmRequest.$valid||!r.DataUseAgreement||(!chkBMT&&!chkOncore&&!chkCAISIS&&!chkLIMS&&!chkFCR)"
        ng-click="SaveData()">
  <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit
</button>
```

How to disable this one after one click?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean *by one click*?

Comment: all inputs, checkboxes and selects add required

Answer (score 7):

Simple. You write to element a bit of javascript, like `onclick="this.disabled=true"` .

```html
<button id="submitRequest" onclick="this.disabled=true" class="btn btn-primary btn-active" ng-disabled="!frmRequest.$valid||!r.DataUseAgreement||(!chkBMT&&!chkOncore&&!chkCAISIS&&!chkLIMS&&!chkFCR)" ng-click="SaveData()"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit</button>
```

Comment: This will disable the button one click,but it doesnt allow form submission too for first click.

Answer (score 5):

**Disabling button after one click**

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"
value="Submit" ng-disabled="button.disabled"/>
```

**In Controller,where u submit the form just add**

```
scope.button={};
scope.button.disabled=true;
```

This disables the button after one click form submission

Answer (score 2):

In your SaveData() function, add below line in beginning of function:

```
$scope.saving=true;
```

then, in your ng-disabled condition, add additional condition:

```
saving||!frmRequest.$valid||!r.DataUseAgreement||(!chkBMT&&!chkOncore&&!chkCAISIS&&!chkLIMS&&!chkFCR)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straight forward. You just have to add one more Boolean condition in your ng-disable statement.

```
 <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="ctrl.isSubmit()" ng-disabled="ctrl.submitClicked">Submit</button>
```

And in your Controller

```
var vm=this;
vm.submitClicked=false;

vm.isSubmit= function(){
vm.submitClicked= true;
}
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3599JnHJayhHnyt6KdWw?p=preview) that I made for you