# Angular disable button after click?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have multiple button im trying to disable the button after getting the response.Im using ngClass to disable the button after the getting the response

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data">

  <td>{{item.username}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
                   <td><button  type="button" [ngClass]="{disabled : item.username === name }" (click)="changestatus(item.username)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" >Change Status</button></td>

</tr>
```

And my changestatus function

```
public name : string ;

 changestatus(username : string){

         this.httpService.changeuserstatus({uname : username }).subscribe(data => {

           this.name = (data.data == 1) ? username : "no";

         })

  }
```

im assigning the username value to the name variable and if both matches i will disable the button

The problem is if i click the 1st button after the getting response it is disabled but when i click the 2nd button the after getting response 1st button is enabled and the 2nd button becomes disabled.But the thing is need to disable both buttons. Help me thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618463/disable-submit-button-after-one-click-in-angularjs

Comment: Try this: `[ngClass]="{disabled :  item.temp || (item.username === name && item.temp = true) }"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@maciej-caputa is correct regarding the use of `[disabled]` rather than a class, but your error is actually due to your application logic.

Your function `changestatus()` updates the global variable `this.name`.
This will affect all rows, since their `disabled` state is conditional on `'item.username === name'`

Try the following - I'm assuming that `item` is of a type called `User` (to which you will need to add a new property `isDisabled`:

Model:

```
export class User {
  username: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  isDisabled: boolean;
}
```

component.html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data">
    <td>{{item.username}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.phone}}</td>
    <td><button  type="button" [disabled]="item.isDisabled" (click)="changestatus(item)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" >Change Status</button></td>
</tr>
```

component.ts:

```
    changestatus(user: User){
        this.httpService.changeuserstatus({uname : user.username }).subscribe(data => {
            user.isDisabled = (data.data == 1);
        });
    }
```

Very simple plunkr demonstrating a working version: https://plnkr.co/edit/quLBCMoFtragJ32OBTvp

Comment: i have multiple buttons and if click the 1st button it should be disable and i click the 2nd button it should be disabled without enabling the 1st button and your answer enables the 1st button on clicking the 2nd button

Comment: @ArunKumaresh There were some typos before - The plunkr demonstrates a working version using this approach

Answer (score 6):

To really have disabled button you need to use `disabled` attribute on button element otherwise you will only change styles but still be able to click it. In angular2 you can bind to an attribute as follows.

```
<button [disabled]='item.username === name'></button>
```

Comment: this what i have also tried but gives the same result what i mentioned.The problem is every time the name variable gets the new value

Comment: You can move `item.username === name` to a public method on a component and then call `<button [disabled]='isDisabled()'></button>` it's a good practise and might help you double check the logic. If you need to style it then refer to it by `button:disabled` (`:disabled` pseudo class).

Comment: note i have i multiple buttons what you saying will work when there is single buttons

Comment: Add a class to it, e.g. `<button class='original-button' [disabled]='item.username === name'></button>` and then in css `.original-button:disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<button type="button"
        (click)="changestatus(item.username)"
        [disabled]='isDisabled(item)' 
        class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Change Status</button>
```

TS :

```
isDisabled(item) : boolean {
 return item && item.username === name;
}
```